# Stopping mouseX tracking in processing depending on a condition

Tags: processing

everyone. I'm a novice so excuse my ignorance. I basically want to stop registering mouseX depending on a condition. Let's say that I have a red area and inside that area a yellow circle. When the cursor is inside the red area I want the circle to track the moseX coordinates (while maintaining y-axis position) but I also want the circle to 'remember' the moseX coordinates as soon as the cursor leaves the area.

Here is the code I tried to do:

```java
void setup ()
{
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw () 
{
  background(255);
  noStroke();
  fill(#F05757);
  quad(0, 0, 300, 0, 300, 200, 0, 200);
  fill(#EDF057);
  ellipse(motion(),100,40,40);
}

int motion ()
{
  int currentXValue = 0;
  int savedXValue = currentXValue;

  if (mouseX > 0 && mouseX < 300 && mouseY > 0 && mouseY < 200)
  {
    currentXValue = mouseX;
    savedXValue = currentXValue;
  } else {}

  return savedXValue;
}
```

When the cursor leaves the red area I don't want the circle to go back to X = 0, I want it to maintain the last stored x coordinates. I tried to make the variable currentXValue to track mouseX and saveXValue to remember the coordinates for when the cursor leaves the red area.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the `currentXValue` variable inside the `draw()` loop and setting it equal to 0. Then you only change it if the mouse is inside the red area.

You need to keep track of the previous value of the `currentXValue` variable. In other words, you need to define the variable outside of the `motion()` function, at the sketch level:

```java
int currentXValue = 0;

void setup ()
{
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw () 
{
  background(255);
  noStroke();
  fill(#F05757);
  quad(0, 0, 300, 0, 300, 200, 0, 200);
  fill(#EDF057);
  ellipse(motion(), 100, 40, 40);
}

int motion ()
{

  int savedXValue = currentXValue;

  if (mouseX > 0 && mouseX < 300 && mouseY > 0 && mouseY < 200)
  {
    currentXValue = mouseX;
    savedXValue = currentXValue;
  } else {
  }

  return savedXValue;
}
```

Now the `currentXValue` will persists between calls to the `draw()` function. Also note that your `savedXValue` is not needed.

Shameless self-promotion: I've written a tutorial on animation in Processing available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/animation).

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I was trying to do. I'll totally check your tutorials!